# Exercise about quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying for an exam, and I can't figure out this problem: 
Let $p$ be a prime. Then show that $(\mathbb{F}_p[X]/\langle X^2 +X +1\rangle,+,\cdot)$ is a field if and only if $p \equiv 2\,\,\, (\text{mod}\, 3)$.
Could someone perhaps give a hint? (ideally not the entire solution)
I know that it is a field if and only if $X^2 +X +1$ is irreducable. Since it is of degree two, it will be irreducable if it has no roots. Can this be used?
Thank you

Comment: Hint: The quadratic formula works in any field, depending only on whether the expression under the square root is a perfect square in that field. (Alternatively, you can verify that the roots of this specific cyclotomic polynomial are elements of multiplicative order 3.)

Comment: That make sense! However, when pluggin the numbers into the quadratic formula, I get that $\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{p-3}$ under modulo $p$ has to be 'well defined' you could say  for there to be roots. How do I proceed?

Comment: The tool to determine whether numbers have square roots modulo prime is [the law of Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you! I don't think my professor intended us to use this law of Quadratic Reciprocity. Can you  explain why the roots must have multiplicative order 3?

Comment: Basically because $X^2+X+1$ is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_3(X)$. More concretely, every root of $X^2+X+1$ is a root of $(X^2+X+1)(X-1) = X^3-1$, but is not a root of $X-1$ (unless $q=3$), and so the order of that root must be....

Answer (score 1):

As you observe, you only need to check when the quadratic will have no roots.

Observe that if $p=2$ then the condition is trivially true, so from now $p\ge 5$

Now $4$ is coprime to $p$, hence the quadratic has no root iff $$ 4x^2 + 4x+4$$ has no root.

Also $4x^2 + 4x+4 = (1+2x)^2 + 3$, and this equation will have no root iff $3$ is a quadratic non residue mod $p$.
Use reciprocity law to conclude